# Coupons in Magento

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, coupon

I am trying to set up a coupon that will follow the rule of:

```
Buy X of Product 1 get Y of Product 2 free.
```

So far I am unable to come up with the set of rules that will allow me to do this.  Is it even possible or is there possibly a module that will allow me to make this rule a reality.

Comment: We implemented a giveaway extension, which always gives you one free product. Maybe you can use that or fork it which could reduce your implementation effort: https://github.com/sitewards/Giveaway

Answer (score 2):

How about a regular sales rule with:

- Condition: SKU is Product-X
- Action: Percent of Product Price
- Discount Amount: 100
- Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 2
- Apply the rule to items only matching the following conditions:

  - SKU is Product-Y

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box as far as I know. I know Mageworld has an extension that adds a free gift product but only one free gift per one product.

I did come across [this extension](https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-buy-x-get-y-free) a while ago but since on that project the cart controller was already overwritten I couldn't use it. Also it's in beta so a lot of testing is advised.

We ultimately ended up building our own extension observing the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` and `checkout_cart_update_items_after` events to add or remove the free products